# Как запретить повторный вызов файла PHP, пока он не закончил работу

Tags: php

Есть файл PHP, который принимает POST запрос и начинает обновлять БД.
Как запретить вызов этого файла, пока не будет закончена операция обновления БД?
Вызывать этот файл могут разные компьютеры.

Пока есть вариант хранить статус процесса в файле, насколько это правильно, нету других механизмов?

Comment: создать файл, удалить по окончании. Создать файл, локировать на время работы скрипта....

Comment: вам нужно менять логику работы приложения, а не файлы блокировать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

создаете некую таблицу, с процессом, и состоянием, пока в 1 из процесса состояние - "в работе" - не запускаете других.

Закончился процесс, ему статус "done", берёте следующий.

Чтобы запустить все по очереди, можно воспользоватся механизмом очередей, и(опционально) готовыми под это инструментами, типа `redis`

Comment: очереди вроде не в redis а в rabbitMQ

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  не скажу насчет rabbit, с ним не работал. Но в redis точно есть очереди